# Should you join() a completed daemon Thread?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have some worker threads consuming data from a pre-populated input queue, and putting results into another queue.

```
import queue
import threading

worker_count = 8
input_queue = queue.Queue()
output_queue = queue.Queue()

threads = []
for _ in range(worker_count):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=perform_work, args=(input_queue, output_queue)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)
```

I am processing the results in the main thread, and I want to make sure I process all of the results.

```
while True:
    try:
        result = output_queue.get(True, 0.1)
    except queue.Empty:
        pass
    else:
        process_result(result)

    if not any([t.is_alive() for t in threads]) and not output_queue.empty():
        # All results have been processed, stop.
        break
```

Is it safe to just use [`.is_alive()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.is_alive) in this case? Or is there a particular reason to use [`.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join) instead?

NOTE: I'm making my threads `daemon = True` because it makes it easier to debug and terminate the program.

Comment: Are tasks being streamed into `input_queue`? (If not, you should look at `multiprocessing.dummy` instead, which abstracts this sort of thing into a nice `pool.imap_unordered()` call for you.)

Comment: @AKX The `input_queue` is fully populated before hand.

Comment: @AKX `pool.imap_unordered()` looks like a better way to accomplish what I'm doing.

Comment: Glad to help (in a roundabout way). Note that `multiprocessing` will spawn new Python processes, and `multiprocessing.dummy` uses threads.